# Updating data in a cell with data from another cell when a specific outcome is reached

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to make it so that when one cell (**B1**) reaches a value of 0, **A1** which is text entered by user, is now replaced with the data in **C1** which is also data entered by the user. Meaning that formulas cannot be placed in either **A1** or **C1** as they are data inputted by user (B1 already has formula calculating its value.)

Instinctly I want to use =IF(B1=0,A1=C1,"") but obviously that doesn't work as A1 = C1 is checking if they equal each other, not replacing A1 with C1.

There's probably going to be a simple solution to this but I cannot figure out a way to make it work.

Comment: You need reference cells for this or you will have to trigger this through code.You cannot simply replace cells when B1 reaches zero.

Comment: @ImranMalek would you be able to explain how to do this or provide a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to have formulas and user input reside in the same field. For this you would need a VBA solution like the following.

Using the macro editor (alt+f11) place the following inside the sheet where the code needs to trigger:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal rng As Range)
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    'only trigger on when column 2 experiences a change
    If rng.Column = 2 And rng.Value2 = 0 Then
        Set sh = rng.Parent
        sh.Cells(rng.Row, 1).Value2 = sh.Cells(rng.Row, 3).Value2
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that Column B is numbered as 2 here, and C is 3, etc..
This 'overwrite' will only trigger, when column B changes to 0, it will not force C into A when the user overwrites A afterwards. If you want it to trigger whenever A, B or C change, then rewrite the trigger condition to:

```
If rng.Column <= 3 And rng.Value2 = 0 Then
```

If this answer was helpful to you, please don't forget to vote. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting runtime error 438 on the if statement, saying object doesnt support this property or method? cant seem to get rid of it

Comment: Thanks for trying. Are you getting the error on a simple new excel file with just the values as described in your requirement? For example: A1:"a", B1:"2", "C1":"d"? Then change B1 to 0.

Comment: Yeah it does work in a new file, just have to try figure out why it doesn't work in mine now!

Comment: I think the problem comes from the fact the value in 'B2' is the result of a formula within a different sheet. Just replicated this in a blank sheet and the code only runs when you press enter on a cell on column B, it doesn't simply run when the value is changed to 0. Any idea on how to get it to work?

Comment: You are right, the way it's written it will only trigger when the user changes the value in B2. The only other approach I can think of is to trigger when something changes on the other sheet where the actual changes happen, then go through ALL rows of B and check if any have changed to zero. The problem is, this would trigger on any change in that other sheet and depending on the count of rows in B, it could also be quite slow. Let me know if you want to give that a shot. You'll have to be comfortable with adapting some things in the vba code references though, to make it fit your project.

Comment: Yeah the other sheet will be constantly changed by the user and there is plenty of rows so it probably wouldnt go down too well. Simplest of problems requires such a complex solution...

Comment: Perhaps there's a completely different way of how you can display that information without even needing the original requirement. For example you could use conditional formatting to white-out cells in A, when B is zero, so that the user can effectively only see column C, as A's color is white text on white background. Or you could split A and C into 4 columns, two to input, two for display (containing formulas with Cx=0 / Cx<>0).

Comment: Good concept, I'll briefly explain what the system does to give you a better idea. The column "A" is a batch number of a product, column "c" holds the backup batch so when A is empty they take it from C. The white-out would work but I call the batch number from A and display it on another sheet that the primary user will be using.

Comment: So now I'm thinking to make A appear red so stores operative know that batch is empty, and to make the formula on the other sheet to call the batch number from C instead of A when B = 0.

Comment: I was about to offer the exact same idea after reading the first part. I think you've reached a working solution. Congratulations! :-)

Comment: Just tried it and it works, thank you very much for your help! I'll be sure to give you all the upvotes I can when it lets me :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the equal sign when using a cell in a formula:

```
=IF(B1=0,C1,"")
```

Comment: This would only work if the formula was written in A1, right? I can't put the formula in there as the user inputs data there